# Prove that Monte Carlo integration works

Tags: probability, integration, numerical-methods, monte-carlo

Given N uniform samples

$$ \overline{x}_1{,}\ \overline{x}_2{,}\ \dots{,}\ \overline{x}_N \in \Omega ,$$
I am trying to prove that Monte Carlo integration works, so $$ \int_{\Omega}^{ }f\left(\overline{x}\right)d\overline{x}=\int_{\Omega}^{ }d\overline{x}\cdot\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf\left(\overline{x}_i\right).$$

So far I have got (by law of large numbers) that $$ \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf\left(\overline{x}_i\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(f\left(\overline{x}\right)\right)=\int_{\Omega}^{ }f\left(\overline{x}\right)\rho\left(f\left(\overline{x}\right)\right)d\overline{x},$$
where $ \rho\left(f\left(\overline{x}\right)\right) $ is probability density function of $ f \left(  \overline{x}\right).$

So is it automatically true that $ \rho \left( f  \left( \overline{x} \right) \right) $ is the same as probability density function of $ \overline{x}?$ Or how could the proof be completed? Since $ \overline{x} $ is uniformly distributed, does it follow that $ f \left( \overline{x} \right) $ is uniformly distributed, too?

Comment: I think that after "where", you should go with single `$`, not double ones. It would greatly improve readability in my opinion.

Comment: @user3733558 Can you help with this?

Comment: I'm a software engineer, and I've implemented MC a few times in my career, typically UCT and NMCS, so I've been using MC a lot, but without knowing much about its theoretical foundations. When I saw the title of your question, I felt curious about it, and I thought the presentation could be improved, therefore I commented. Now, I'm unfortunately not very familiar with this type of proofs, so I'm afraid I can only wait with you for someone else's help.